# Was /etc/yum/repos.d ever a thing?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, history

In some places I've read, users have mentioned the path `/etc/yum/repos.d` along side `/etc/yum.repos.d`. Was this a path that actually used at some point?

I even loaded of CentOS 5.11 and it's still `/etc/yum.repos.d`. Was this other path ever used? It seems odd that the repos.d directory *isn't* inside `/etc/yum`. Does anyone know the history of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a thing up until CentOS 5. [`man yum.conf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=yum.conf&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=CentOS%205.11&arch=default&format=html) had:

```
reposdir    A  list of directories where yum should look for .repo
files which define repositories to use. Default is `/etc/yum/re-
pos.d'.
```

(But elsewhere in that manpage, and in `man yum`, the path mentioned is `/etc/yum.repos.d`. This might have been the transitional version.)

In [CentOS 6](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=yum.conf&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=CentOS%206.0&arch=default&format=html), that became:

```
reposdir    A  list of directories where yum should look for .repo
files which define repositories to use. Default is `/etc/yum.re-
pos.d'.
```